# Social media platform

Tags: php, social-networks

I am a member of a group on Facebook and we are looking to setup outside FB now, and so I have been looking at social media platforms but am struggling to make up my mind.

I was hoping that you guys might have an opinion on what is the best platform available that will be easy enough to setup and at a good price. Also, the security of the application is of particular importance to my community.

I have reviewed several social media platforms so far and have now narrowed the selection down to 3:

- Open Source Social Network
- Wowonder
- crea8SocialPro

However, I have an issue with all three being that they all need `allow_url_fopen` to be enabled, but I don't know why and have read that this can be a security issue.

I would appreciate anyone's opinions on these platforms and this particular setting or any alternative you can recommend.

Comment: It’s not on-topic to ask for opinions on software. You should describe what features you need, and additionally you may list which software you found (and you may note why they are probably no good match).

Comment: Apart from that, we do not recommend *platforms* here but *software*. We do not do [A vs B](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) either, as @unor already pointed out. From your question it's not exactly clear what you are after: Wanting to set up "your own Diaspora" on your own server running PHP, and looking for appropriate libraries or complete software packages? Then please go with unor's advice, [edit] your post and fill the gaps. Without clarification, your question will very likely be put on hold.

Comment: *best*, *easy* and *good* are all not measurable. Please gives us hard information. And if *the security of the application is of particular importance to my community* **where are your specific security requirements**? Also, there is **no** information about the features your platform should have. Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information), make some good lists of requirements and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

My name is Arsalan. I am the team leader of [Open Source Social Network (OSSN)](https://www.opensource-socialnetwork.org/). Let me try to answer your question `allow_url_fopen` allows developers to fetch files using complete URL, like file_get_contents('mywebsite.com/myfile.txt'). However we don't see any security issue regarding this. `allow_url_fopen` information is misinterpreted by many developers. We need this to be enabled to fetch files from internet directly.

The security issue comes when software is not secure, however OSSN is free from any security bugs till now. For OSSN , its safe to use `allow_url_fopen`

If you have any other question feel free to post it to our community website and we are happy to answer your questions.

Comment: This [database code](https://github.com/opensource-socialnetwork/opensource-socialnetwork/blob/b300b7ae96d35a013283706fddc7c5eea248530a/classes/OssnDatabase.php) looks _extremely_ unsafe. I suspect the reason your software is "free from any security bugs till now" is because nobody's looked.